# Can a Safari extension save a cookie locally?

Tags: javascript, cookies, xmlhttprequest, safari-extension

There is a known issue where webkit browsers throw you a login popup with https sites under certain conditions. I notice it if my cookie is no longer valid.

I have an extension that accesses your Google sites but this login prompt thing is a bear to overcome. I can login to Goog's sites via perl/php and libcurl, save the needed cookies to a text file and go forward.

Can Safari extensions and XHR do the same? Can I save a cookie and its data to either memory or a variable? Can I use the cookie data in said variable in an XHR request? This would potentially overcome my problem.